# Mount SMB share without specifying shared directory in remote path

Tags: debian, ubuntu, mount, smb

I was about to change mount from "//192.168.1.x/SomeFolder" to "//192.168.1.x/" so i could choose which dataset i want to access with my docker containers.

It gave me error like:

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

Any ideas how to mount remote SMB share without specifying dataset / folder?

PS: this is the mounting command i'm using:
`sudo mount -t cifs -o rw,vers=3.0,credentials=REDACTED //192.168.1.72/SomeFolder /mnt/NAS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "//192.168.1.x/SomeFolder", "SomeFolder" is not a folder. It is a name of a *share*. That is by design of SMB protocol. There is literally no way to do "//192.168.1.x/" in SMB. The name of a "share" is an absolute necessity.

That said, there is a way to workaround it. Assuming you have several shares on your NAS (SomeFolder, AnotherFolder, AnotherOne), you can create in your /mnt/NAS a set of directories mimicking the set of shares, and then mount each of them separately. In this case you would have a script (or set of entries in fstab) like this:

```
mount -t cifs -o rw,vers=3.0,credentials=REDACTED //192.168.1.72/SomeFolder /mnt/NAS/SomeFolder 
mount -t cifs -o rw,vers=3.0,credentials=REDACTED //192.168.1.72/AnotherFolder /mnt/NAS/AnotherFolder 
mount -t cifs -o rw,vers=3.0,credentials=REDACTED //192.168.1.72/AnotherOne /mnt/NAS/AnotherOne
```

So now, your /mnt/NAS - has several entry points exactly as you desired.
The disadvantage - you have to update the mounting script if you create a new share on the NAS. But it does work.

Comment: Thank you for straight forward answer! I become thinking that it isn't possible as on Windows is as those are completely different systems with different techniques of mounting network attached storage. In fact, i don't even think windows really mount the storage like Linux does. It just send requests and remotely.